# Combining rows of different tables into one row that can have a value

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I'm trying to figure out a data model for the following problem:

I have a list of **`energy sources`**

```
| name             |
|------------------|
| windmill         |
| oil              |
| water_powerplant |
```

a list of **`attributes`**:

```
| name    |
|---------|
| location|
| size    |
| oil_type|
```

a list of attribute **`values`**:

```
| name    |attribute|
|---------|---------|
| offshore|location |
| onshore |location |
| big     |size     |
| small   |size     |
| crude   |oil_type |
| bunker  |oil_type |
```

and a list of which **`energy sources`** can have which **`attributes`**:

```
| source          |attribute|
|-----------------|---------|
| windmill        |location |
| windmill        |size     |
| oil             |oil_type |
| water_powerplant|size     |
```

What I need now is a table where I can store energy values for each combination of source and attribute value. For example how would I store the value of an `small offshore windmill`? The best I can come up with is coming up with some custom convention for combining multiple attribute values into one value...

```
| source          |attribute_values             |kwh_per_hour|
|-----------------|-----------------------------|------------|
| windmill        |size=small location=offshore |285         |
```

or creating a fixed amount of column for attributes. This however would limit the flexibility a lot.

```
| source          |att_1|att_val_1|attr_2  |attr_val_2|kwh_per_hour|
|-----------------|-----|---------|--------|----------|------------|
| windmill        |size |small    |location|offshore  |285         |
```

Is there some good solution out there already on how to do this?

Comment: This sounds very much like a [EAV model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model). No, you should definitely not use a fixed amount of columns and store it denormalised.

Comment: You could try using a `jsonb` column for the attributes. But since this is tagged [relational database], it sounds like you actually want to model this with foreign keys to ensure that only valid combinations are entered?

Comment: `jsonb` might actually be a good solution. I'm not really worried about valid combinations since it's a small scale project and I'm entering data myself. I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your data processing mode. For OLTP case you can extend with EAV model. For OLAP, all attribute names became the dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

In an [entity-attribute-value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) you'd have a table with these three columns, and could ensure your data integrity with foreign key references:

```
CREATE TABLE powerplants (
  source text REFERENCES energy_sources(name),
  id integer,
  kwh_per_hour float,
  PRIMARY KEY (source, id)
);
CREATE TABLE powerplant_attribute_values (
  source text,
  id integer,
  attribute text,
  value text,
  PRIMARY KEY (source, id, attribute),
  FOREIGN KEY (source, id) REFERENCES powerplants,
  FOREIGN KEY (source, attribute) REFERENCES valid_attributes(source, attribute),
  FOREIGN KEY (attribute, value) REFERENCES valid_values(attribute, name)
);
```

(The `valid_attributes` and `valid_values` tables would themselves have foreign key references to `energy_sources(name)` and `attributes(name)`, for which you could alternatively use `ENUM`s)

To query your plants in a nice string, you'd use

```
SELECT format("A %s %s with %sKW",
  (SELECT string_agg(eav.value, ' ')
    FROM powerplant_attribute_values eav
    WHERE eav.source = pp.source AND eav.id = pp.id
    -- ORDER BY eav.attribute for reproducible result?
  ),
  pp.source,
  pp.kwh_per_hour)
FROM powerplants pp;
```

Alternatively, if you don't care that much about the database doing attribute validation for you, just use a `jsonb` column:

```
CREATE TABLE powerplants (
  source text,
  attribute_values jsonb,
  kwh_per_hour float
);
```

```
SELECT format("A %s %s with %sKW",
  (SELECT string_agg(value, ' ')
    FROM jsonb_each_text(pp.attribute_values) AS kv(attribute, value)
  ),
  pp.source,
  pp.kwh_per_hour)
FROM powerplants pp;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this might solve my question.